# Show Categories and Post Titles for Custom Post Type Archive - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I'm trying to set up a custom post archive page where the categories for that custom post are displayed, and the posts within that category displayed underneath.

The page in question is in development at http://vinnypeculiar.com/wp/lyrics

The post type is called Lyrics, and the categories within that type are called Albums (individually category listed as 'album').

So the archive page should look like:

ALBUM NAME #1

- Song #1 from ALBUM
- Song #2 from ALBUM

ALBUM NAME #2

- Song #1 from ALBUM
- Song #2 from ALBUM

At the moment, with the code I'm using, it successfully shows the album names, but it shows EVERY post under each category, which is not correct.

The code I'm using almost works, but I think it just needs to be tweaked somehow:

```
<?php
/*Template Name: Lyrics*/
get_header();?>

<div id="content">

<h2>Lyrics & Poems</h2>

<?php
//get all categories then display all posts in each term
$taxonomy = 'album';
$param_type = 'album__in';
$term_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
if ($terms) {
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args=array(
      "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
      'post_type' => 'lyrics',
    'category' => '%album%',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC'
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {  ?>
      <div class="category section">
        <h3><?php echo ''.$term->name;?></h3>
        <ul>
        <?php
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
       <?php
      endwhile;
      ?>
      </ul>
      </div>
 <?php
    }
  }
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>


</div>


<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this here -- http://wordimpress.com/loop-through-categories-and-display-posts-within/

Answer (score 0):

To display page title in custom post type (inside WordPress) include the supports parameter within your register_post_type() arguments declaration (in your functions.php file):

```
    $args = array( 
    'supports' => array('title'),
    );
```